# Magento2 composer authentication issue

Tags: magento2, composer, docker

I want to create docker file using alankent/gsd image.And I'm getting authentication issue.here -i option is not working.I'm using windows 10 as a host.

how to attach my public key & private key to dockerfile?

```
FROM alankent/gsd
RUN cd /magento2
RUN composer require "magento/product-community-edition:2.1.0" --no-update
RUN composer update
RUN php bin/magento cache:clean
RUN php bin/magento setup:upgrade
RUN php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy




docker build   -t sivajik34/m2upgrade .
    Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
    Step 1 : FROM alankent/gsd
     ---> 2e0b231762c2
    Step 2 : RUN cd /magento2
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 382f13a77358
    Step 3 : RUN composer require "magento/product-community-edition:2.1.0" --no-update
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 7a380a0306c1
    Step 4 : RUN composer update
     ---> Running in 0ffb5bfab433
    Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted
    Loading composer repositories with package information


      [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
      The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.
      You must be using the interactive console to authenticate


    update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

    The command '/bin/sh -c composer update' returned a non-zero code: 255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add authentifications to the ~/.composer/auth.json with the composer config command:

```
composer config -a -g http-basic.your.domain.com username password
```

Comment: so i need to add 'composer config -a -g http-basic.your.domain.com username password' in Dockerfile.but here what need to give  http-basic.your.domain.com?

Comment: I'm using in my local system.

Comment: The domain of the repositories you want to add authentifocation for. For example repo.magento.com

Comment: now i'm getting this error: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                               
  The 'http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%2429ae60b62e12d7e5d86427c4b8a56951a90b38cb2b3f7d678099bc8c48f7af49.json' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: FWIW, Magento is working on a Docker container and it prompts you for your credentials (you might have to run Composer in interactive mode to do that). There is at least one alternative, which is to use HTTPS with a personal access token. That would probably require a `credentials.yml` or other file that contains the token and your GitHub URL in Docker would look something like `git clone https://$1@<rest of url>`